# Session-like storage option for a non-serializable object?

Tags: c#, session, asynchronous, storage, waithandle

### Background (Skip this part if you want)

**Feel free to skip over this part if you choose, it's just some background for those who want to better understand the problem**

At the beginning of one action on my site, I kick off several asynchronous operations. The action returns before the operations are complete. This is what I want. However, the `View` that gets loaded by this action invokes several other actions in a different controller. Some of these actions rely on the results of the async calls from the first page, so I need to be able to wait on the async calls to finish from the other controller. I thought about just using `Session` to store the WaitHandles, but as WaitHandles aren't serializable, I obviously can't do that.

---

### Short version:

I need to be able to store an async `WaitHandle` object somewhere from one controller, such that it can be reliably retrieved in a different controller. These `WaitHandles` also need to be user-specific, but I can handle that part. Just don't list an option that would make doing that impossible.

Comment: And did you want that to scale to multiple servers?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, yeah, but all the load balancing is taken care of at a higher level, so I would think I shouldn't have to worry about that

Comment: Think again. Can you assure all related actions will run on the same server?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, I don't know. I'd guess so, but I've never looked into the way we do load balancing around here as it isn't done by my team. I would guess the LB would be done per-session, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Also think about handling the resources. One aborted page and the server is left with a lot of dangling WaitHandles.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thought about it, but there's only 4 calls on the page, and only 1-2 that I need to actually implement this pattern on. On the "waiting" page, I had planned on checking for the existence and validity of the waithandle and then handling it accordingly. If its null or I catch an InvalidOperationException on deserializing, I'll get rid of it. Else, use it

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you think of a way to do this? Maybe a static object in my basecontroller or something?

Comment: A static object would also be limited to 1 memory space. No solution there. I would try to restructure it to rely on the HTTP protocol only.